# SQL - select name and address of all departments having max number of employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables:

**department**

```
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME      ADDRESS            
------------- -------------------- --------------------
       10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK            
       20 RESEARCH             DALLAS              
       30 SALES                CHICAGO             
       40 IT                   DALLAS              
       50 EXECUTIVE            NEW YORK            
       60 MARKETING            CHICAGO
```

**employee**

```
Employee_ID  employee_name  job                     manager_ID  hire_date  salary  commission  department_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7839        KING            PRESIDENT                           20-NOV-01   5000                50
7596        JOST            VICE PRESIDENT          7839        04-MAY-01   4500                50
7603        CLARK           VICE PRESIDENT          7839        12-JUN-01   4000                50
7566        JONES           PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT       7596        05-APR-01   3000                10
7886        STEEL           PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT       7566        08-MAR-03   2500                10
7610        WILSON          ANALYST                 7596        03-DEC-01   3000                20
7999        WOLFE           ANALYST                 7610        15-FEB-02   2500                20
7944        LEE             ANALYST                 7610        04-SEP-06   2400                20
7900        FISHER          SALESMAN                7603        06-DEC-01   3000    500         30
7921        JACKSON         SALESMAN                7900        25-FEB-05   2500    400         30
7952        LANCASTER       SALESMAN                7900        06-DEC-06   2000    150         30
7910        SMITH           DATABASE ADMINISTRATOR  7596        20-DEC-01   2900                40
7788        SCOTT           PROGRAMMER              7910        15-JAN-03   2500                40
7876        ADAMS           PROGRAMMER              7910        15-JAN-03   2000                40
7934        MILLER          PROGRAMMER              7876        25-JAN-02   1000                40
8000        BREWSTER        TBA                                 22-AUG-13   2500
```

I need to display the name and address with the exception of Dallas, having the maximum number of employees.

I have written this:

```
SELECT department_name, address
FROM department
WHERE department_id IN
                 (SELECT   MAX(department_id)
                  FROM     department
                  WHERE    UPPER(address) != 'DALLAS')
ORDER BY department_name;
```

But I'm only getting one line

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME      ADDRESS            
-------------------- --------------------
MARKETING            CHICAGO
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, why wouldn't you get a single record back? What were you expecting?  And second, why are you doing `MAX(department_id)`?  What do you think that does?

Comment: All you are going to get is one line, because you are saying match the department ids to the max department id. So, the highest value department id.

You need to using a group by with a "having count".

Comment: i've tried this and still can't get it to work. I've tried 
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT MAX(count(*))
                  FROM  employee
                  GROUP BY department_id)

Comment: So what is the expected result? `SALES` and `EXECUTIVE`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question, but I *think* you want this:

```
with emp_count as (
  select d.department_name,
         d.address,
         count(*) as num_emps, 
         max(count(*)) over () as max_count
  from department d 
    join employee e on d.department_id = e.department_id
  where address <> 'DALLAS'
  group by d.department_name, d.address
)
select * 
from emp_count
where num_emps = max_count;
```

This returns:

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME | ADDRESS  | NUM_EMPS
----------------+----------+---------
SALES           | CHICAGO  |        3
EXECUTIVE       | NEW YORK |        3
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05db83/1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data the city seems to be recorded in the `address` column of the `department` table, and that more than one department can have the same city.

Given this, and the fact that you want to "exclude Dallas," as you say, I would assume you want to filter out all departments where the associated `address` column is 'Dallas'.

However, I don't know if...

1. you want to exclude departments at Dallas if they happen to be tied with other department(s) for the most employees, or
2. if you want to exclude departments at Dallas from being considered when determining what the highest number of employees is at any department.

If (1) is true:

```
select *
  from department_tbl
 where department_id in (select department_id
                           from employee_tbl
                          group by department_id
                         having count(*) = (select max(num_emps)
                                             from (select department_id,
                                                          count(*) as num_emps
                                                     from employee_tbl
                                                    group by department_id)))
   and address <> 'DALLAS';
```

If (2) is true:

```
select *
  from department_tbl
 where department_id in (select department_id
                           from employee_tbl
                          group by department_id
                         having count(*) = (select max(num_emps)
                                             from (select department_id,
                                                          count(*) as num_emps
                                                     from employee_tbl
                                                    where address <> 'DALLAS'
                                                    group by department_id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT d.department_name, 
       d.address 
FROM   department d 
       JOIN employee e 
         ON ( d.department_id = e.department_id ) 
WHERE  d.address <> 'DALLAS' 
GROUP  BY d.department_name, 
          d.address 
HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT Max(cnt) 
                   FROM   (SELECT Count(*) CNT 
                           FROM   employee e 
                           WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' 
                                              FROM   department d 
                                              WHERE  d.department_id = 
                                                     e.department_id 
                                                     AND d.address = 'DALLAS') 
                           GROUP  BY department_id))
```

Comment: The problem I had with Brian DeMilia's answer, is if (1) if Dallas has the most employees then his query returns nothing.  I'm guessing you don't want that.  And (2) he doesn't exclude Dallas from the final results, although he explains why he answered it that way.  Still you might not want that either.    I'm still guessing what you want, but my query excludes Dallas and returns two results.  Since this seems like a homework problem, I took a guess that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.department_id)
from employee e, department d
where e.department_id = d.department_id
group by e.department_id, d.department_name 
having count(e.department_id)=(select max(count(department_id)) 
                               from employee 
                               group by department_id);
```

Hope it helps